# Make unirest GET request with Node.js & Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a unirest GET request. I want to get data from an external API inside one of my API routes (using Express) and then fetch that data in my front-end (using ReactJS).

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

This is how far I have come:

**Express server with my GET Route**

```
const express = require('express');
const unirest = require('unirest');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/api/podcasts', (req, res) => {
    //HOW DO I MAKE GET REQUEST EXTERNAL API? WITH UNIREST
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**My ReactJS component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Podcasts extends Component {

  state = {
    response: ''
  };

    componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ podcasts: res }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/podcasts');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>Show data from my state here</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring [here](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html#user-content-requestforeverboolean)

```
const express = require('express');
const unirest = require('unirest');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/api/podcasts', (req, res) => {
  unirest.get('your url').end((response) => {
    //make sure response should be a JSON object
    res.status(200).send(response)
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**EDIT - To convert XML to JSON**

you can convert an `XML` to `JSON` using parse - [xml2json](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json), refer example below

```
let xmlParser = require('xml2json');
let xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestScenario>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeHome">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Login">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Logout">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgePanel">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_AddContract">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
      <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeRoute">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_VerifyContract">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Payment">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeSpectrum">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_ClientFeedback">dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
</TestScenario>`;

console.log(xmlParser.toJson(xmlString));
```

Comment: Ah it works fine! Im trying to get the XML body formated to JSON.. Is this possible?

Comment: @JonasAlvarson Updated the answer for XML to JSON parsing